# Getting right view from two razor libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm writing ASPNET Core web page.
I created two razor view libraries and in each one I created file List.cshtml and controller:

- WebPage.Users

  - List.cshtml
  - UsersController.cs
- WebPage.Clients

  - List.cshtml
  - ClientsController.cs

Both controllers have Index method:

```
public class ClientsViewController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View("~/Pages/Views/List.cshtml");
    }
}

public class UsersViewController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View("~/Pages/Views/List.cshtml");
    }
}
```

StartUp code:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(UsersController).Assembly)
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(ClientsController).Assembly);
 }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>{
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "usersViewController",
                pattern: "modules/users/{action}",
                defaults: new {
                    controller = "UsersView",
                    action = "Index"
                });
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "clientsViewController",
                pattern: "modules/clients/{action}",
                defaults: new {
                    controller = "ClientsView",
                    action = "Index"
                });
        });
     }
```

Now the problem is when I open page "modules/clients/" in browser
it returns view from WebPage.Users.Views. I want to return view from WebPage.Clients.Views assembly.
How can I do this?

Comment: Could you pleas tell me how you call the ClientsController  in Index action? Besides, I suggest you could post more details codes about your StartUp.cs codes.

Comment: I  added full startup and controller code. Controller is called by opening page "modules/clients/" in browser.

Comment: You mean that you create two class library which contains the MVC controller or view or you created two razor class library?